# MySQL: How do I list one column and sum the other?

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm using the following SQL:

```
  SELECT
    a.name as accountName,
    SUM((i.value - i.paidValue)) as oneMonth
  FROM insertions i
  JOIN contracts c ON i.contractId = c.id
  JOIN accounts a ON c.accountId = a.id
  WHERE i.value > i.paidValue
    AND i.isDeleted is FALSE
    AND i.isCanceled is FALSE
    AND i.month = 8
    AND i.year = 2013
```

It should produce output like this:

```
accountName | oneMonth
CompanyA    | 3000 [ which is a sum of 1000, 1000, 1000 ]
CompanyB    | 1000
```

But what it's doing is:

```
accountName | oneMonth
CompanyA    | 4000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the GROUP BY a.id

Comment: You're so right.  If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it for your rep.  Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the group by clause

```
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECTa.name as accountName,SUM((i.value - i.paidValue)) as oneMonth
   FROM insertions i
JOIN contracts c ON i.contractId = c.id
JOIN accounts a ON c.accountId = a.id
   WHERE i.value > i.paidValue
    AND i.isDeleted is FALSE
    AND i.isCanceled is FALSE
    AND i.month = 8
    AND i.year = 2013
Group by a.name
```

This will work..